# How to connect SPICE MI 310 to eclipse Android Device Manager?

Tags: adb, windows, usb-drivers

I want to use my SPICE Mi 310 (with Android 2.3.3) to test my Android applications.
But I am not able to see the device in Android Device Manager in Eclipse.

I have been trying to find a suitable driver for the same, but haven't been successful.
Please help me.
Thanks

[Using Windows 7 64 bit.]